# Showing that $P(E \cup F) + P(E \cup F^c) + P(E^c \cup F) + P(E^c \cup F^c) =3$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, set-theory

I need to prove the following:

> For events $E$ and $F$,
> $$P(E \cup F) + P(E \cup F^c) + P(E^c \cup F) + P(E^c \cup F^c)=3.$$

**Is this proof sufficient?**

By inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$P(E \cup F) + P(E \cup F^c) + P(E^c \cup F) + P(E^c \cup F^c)=$$
$$P(E)+P(F)-P(EF) + $$
$$P(E)+P(F^c)-P(EF^c) + $$
$$P(E^c)+P(F)-P(E^cF) + $$
$$P(E^c)+P(F^c)-P(E^cF^c) + $$

Since $P(A^c) = 1- P(A)$,
the previous term equals:
$$P(E) + P(F) - P(EF)+$$
$$P(E) + 1-P(F) - P(EF^c)+$$
$$1-P(E) + P(F) - P(E^cF)+$$
$$1-P(E) + 1-P(F) - P(E^cF^c)$$
$$=$$
$$4-P(EF)-P(EF^c)-P(E^cF)-P(E^cF^c) = 4-(P(EF)+P(EF^c)+P(E^cF)+P(E^cF^c))$$

Proof that $P(EF)+P(EF^c)+P(E^cF)+P(E^cF^c) = 1$:

$$P(EF) + P(EF^c) = P(E)$$
$$P(E^cF) + P(E^cF^c) = P(E^c)$$
Note that $EF$ and $EF^c$ are mutually exclusive.
And $E^cF$ and $E^cF^c$ are mutually exclusive.

$$P(E) + P(E^c) = P(E \cup E^c) = 1$$

Everything together:
$$4-1 = 3$$

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient. But, unless you recently proved that $P(EF)+P(EF^c)=P(E)$, it might be a good idea add one line to explain why this is true: $$EF \cap EF^c = \emptyset \Longrightarrow P(EF)+P(EF^c) = P(EF\cup EF^c) = P(E(F\cup F^c)) = P(E)$$ But this is pretty obvious, so probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a probability space $\Omega$, every $\omega \in \Omega$ is a member of exactly 3 among the 4 sets
$$ \tag{*} E \cup F, \quad  E \cup F^c, \quad  E^c \cup F, \quad  E^c \cup F^c \,.$$
E.g. if $\omega \in E \cap F$, then $\omega$ is contained in the first 3 sets in $(*)$, but not in the fourth. The other cases are similar. Thus, in a discrete probability space, adding the probabilities of the events in $(*)$ will yield
$$\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} 3 P(\omega) =3 \,.
$$
In  a general probability space, the sum of  the indicators of the events in $(*)$ is identically 3; now take expectations.

Comment: I am not that far in my probability book yet, so I dont know how a probability space is defined. But I have one question: What is the value of P(w) inside the sum?

Comment: @swisstackle $\omega$ is any outcome in the probability space. So, if you add up the probabilities of all outcomes in a probability space, the law of total probabilities says you will get $1$. It is similar to adding $P(E)+P(E^c)=1$, only instead of events, you can add the probability of every individual outcome.

Comment: And since there are exactly 3 probability spaces for each of the outcomes, we multiply by 3 inside the sum?

Comment: Since each outcome is contained in three of the 4 events, when we add up the probabilities of the 4 events, each outcome is counted three times.